# Why doesn't btrfs send | btrfs receive preserve the "no dump" file attribute?

Tags: btrfs, attributes

Btrfs supports the "no dump" file attribute and it is preserved when taking snapshots.  But after sending such a snapshot to another Btrfs using `btrfs send` and `btrfs receive`, all values of the "no dump" attribute are lost.  By contrast the "compress data" attribute values are preserved through that procedure.  Why?

Answer (score 0):

The helpful folk at #btrfs pointed out to me that the answer is up on the web.  That answer is that, as of the time of writing, it's a work in progress.

https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Design_notes_on_Send/Receive#Send_stream_v2_draft